# Fix a closed immersion $i:Y\to X$. What is the image of $i_*:\mathfrak{Qco}(Y)\to\mathfrak{Qco}(X)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Fix a closed immersion of schemes $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$. For which $\mathcal{F}\in\mathfrak{Qco}(X)$ do we have $\mathcal{F}\cong i_*\mathcal{G}$ for some $\mathcal{G}\in\mathfrak{Qco}(Y)$?

I know that $(i_*\mathcal{G})_x=0$ for all $x\in X\setminus Y$, so we must clearly require that $\operatorname{supp}\mathcal{F}\subseteq Y$. However, is this enough?

Comment: If you distinguish between scheme theoretic support and set theoretic support, yes. Given any quasi-coherent sheaf, the annihilator is an ideal sheaf. You must require that the annihilator contains the ideal sheaf of $Y$.